# Need to know the number of 0s that follow each other in python

Tags: python, counter

Do you know a way or a librairy for finding the number of 0s that follow each other:

I have a dico like that :

```
{0: 13518, 1: 5029, 2: 4133, 3: 2304, 4: 1940, 5: 1056, 6: 1317, 7: 779, 8: 862, 9: 735, 10: 776, 11: 537, 12: 633, 13: 521, 14: 737, 15: 606, 16: 676, 17: 533, 18: 567, 19: 439, 20: 494, 21: 321, 22: 305, 23: 176, 24: 170, 25: 93, 26: 86, 27: 63, 28: 54, 29: 25, 30: 34, 31: 17, 32: 17, 33: 16, 34: 16, 35: 16, 36: 10, 37: 4, 38: 6, 39: 7, 40: 14, 41: 5, 42: 5, 43: 1, 44: 1, 45: 2, 46: 0, 47: 1, 48: 2, 49: 3, 50: 3, 51: 5, 52: 14, 53: 31, 54: 6, 55: 94, 56: 21, 57: 72, 58: 11, 59: 17, 60: 24, 61: 3, 62: 0, 63: 1, 64: 2, 65: 1, 66: 1, 67: 0, 68: 1, 69: 0, 70: 3, 71: 0, 72: 1, 73: 0, 74: 0, 75: 0, 76: 0, 77: 1, 78: 0, 79: 0, 80: 1, 81: 0, 82: 1, 83: 0, 84: 1, 85: 1, 86: 2, 87: 7, 88: 1, 89: 0, 90: 1, 91: 5, 92: 1, 93: 3, 94: 1, 95: 1, 96: 0, 97: 0, 98: 0, 99: 0, 100: 3, 101: 0, 102: 0, 103: 0, 104: 0, 105: 0, 106: 0, 107: 0, 108: 0, 109: 0, 110: 0, 111: 0, 112: 0, 113: 0, 114: 0, 115: 0, 116: 0, 117: 0, 118: 0, 119: 0, 120: 0, 121: 0, 122: 0, 123: 0, 124: 0, 125: 0, 126: 0, 127: 0, 128: 0, 129: 0, 130: 0, 131: 0, 132: 0, 133: 0, 134: 0, 135: 0, 136: 0, 137: 0, 138: 0, 139: 0, 140: 0, 141: 0, 142: 0, 143: 0, 144: 0, 145: 0, 146: 0, 147: 0, 148: 0, 149: 0, 150: 0, 151: 0, 152: 0, 153: 0, 154: 0, 155: 0, 156: 0, 157: 0, 158: 0, 159: 0, 160: 0, 161: 0, 162: 0, 163: 0, 164: 0, 165: 0, 166: 0, 167: 0, 168: 0, 169: 0, 170: 0, 171: 0, 172: 0, 173: 0, 174: 0, 175: 0, 176: 0, 177: 0, 178: 0, 179: 0, 180: 0, 181: 0, 182: 0, 183: 0, 184: 0, 185: 0, 186: 0, 187: 0, 188: 0, 189: 0, 190: 0, 191: 0, 192: 0, 193: 0, 194: 0, 195: 0, 196: 0, 197: 0, 198: 0, 199: 0, 200: 0, 201: 0, 202: 0, 203: 0, 204: 0, 205: 0, 206: 0, 207: 0, 208: 0, 209: 0, 210: 1}
```

I need to found for this one :
1 (46)
1 (62)
1 (67)
1 (69)
.
.
.
4 (73 to 76)
2 (78 to 79)
.
.
.

I need a counteur in fact who count the number of 0 until the next number and output the value, restart the counter at 0 And so on.

Comment: There is no library for this because it's trivial for you to set up yourself. You don't appear to have attempted anything, though

Comment: Huge horizontal line, making this hard to understand. I suggest to massively shrink your example (fewer values, and perhaps spread it over multiple lines).

Comment: Also, it's not clear what exactly the result/output shall be.

Comment: And are the keys always the sorted consecutive ints 0,1,2,3,...?

Comment: Sorry for that, Yes i try many things in fact. Don't be so surly.

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can solve it like that, by simply iterating the consequtive keys and storing the beginning of the currently running strip of zeros. Reset the strip if you see non-zero value

```
limit = max(d.keys())
zero_beginning = -1
for i in range(limit+1):
    if d[i] == 0:
        if zero_beginning == -1:
           zero_beginning = i
    else:
        if zero_beginning != -1:
            print(f'Range from {zero_beginning} to {i-1}, size {i - zero_beginning}')
            zero_beginning = -1
```

Output:

```
Range from 46 to 46, size 1
Range from 62 to 62, size 1
Range from 67 to 67, size 1
Range from 69 to 69, size 1
Range from 71 to 71, size 1
Range from 73 to 76, size 4
Range from 78 to 79, size 2
Range from 81 to 81, size 1
Range from 83 to 83, size 1
Range from 89 to 89, size 1
Range from 96 to 99, size 4
Range from 101 to 209, size 109
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have 0 after the key 101...

Comment: You need to use `limit = max(d.keys()) + 1` as the first line, because `range()` excludes the top of the range. This isn't checking the last key of the dict.

Comment: If you change range(limit) by range (len(d)) thats good. Thank you very much for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> data = {0: 13518, 1: 5029, 2: 4133, 3: 2304, 4: 1940, 5: 1056, 6: 1317, 7: 779, 8: 862, 9: 735, 10: 776, ...
>>> [(next(it)[0], 1+sum(1 for _ in it)) for val, it in itertools.groupby(data.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]) if val == 0]
[(46, 1), (62, 1), (67, 1), (69, 1), (71, 1), (73, 4), (78, 2), (81, 1), (83, 1), (89, 1), (96, 4), (101, 109)]
```

Explanation:
`groupby` from itertools creates sub-items of equal values. We run it on the items of the dictionary and pass as key a lambda-function, telling that items with the same value should be grouped.

```
>>> list(itertools.groupby(data.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]))
[(13518, <itertools._grouper object at 0xffcf0b80>), (5029, <itertools._grouper object at 0xffcf0b38>), (4133, <itertools._grouper object at 0xffcf0b50>), (2304, <itertools._grouper object at 0xffcf0b20>), (1940, <itertools._grouper object at 0xffcf0b68>), (1056, <itertools._grouper object at 0xffcf0b08>),...
```

As you can see, `groupby` returns tuples, the first element being the key by which we grouped by (13518 for the first item, ...) and the second item being an iterable "grouper", giving access to the elements in the group.

Next step, we filter out all the items returned by `groupby` where the value is not 0.

```
>>> [(val, it) for val, it in itertools.groupby(data.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]) if val == 0]
[(0, <itertools._grouper object at 0xffca1490>), (0, <itertools._grouper object at 0xffca1418>), (0, <itertools._grouper object at 0xffca14c0>), (0, <itertools._grouper object at 0xffca14d8>), (0, <itertools._grouper object at 0xffca14f0>), (0, <itertools._grouper object at 0xffca1508>) ...
```

Now we want to extract two things from each "grouper" returned by groupby: The first element, for which we use `next` and the number of elements for which we use `sum`. However, there is one pitfall. After the call of `next`, the first item of the "grouper" has been consumed, so we need to add 1 to the result of `sum` to get the correct count.

```
>>> [(next(it), 1+sum(1 for _ in it)) for val, it in itertools.groupby(data.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]) if val == 0]
[((46, 0), 1), ((62, 0), 1), ((67, 0), 1), ((69, 0), 1), ((71, 0), 1), ((73, 0), 4), ((78, 0), 2), ((81, 0), 1), ((83, 0), 1), ((89, 0), 1), ((96, 0), 4), ((101, 0), 109)]
```

Last thing is just cosmetic, as the elements in grouper are tuples and we only care about the first element (knowing that the second element is zero because we filter by it, we adjust our term to:

```
>>> [(next(it)[0], 1+sum(1 for _ in it)) for val, it in itertools.groupby(data.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]) if val == 0]
[(46, 1), (62, 1), (67, 1), (69, 1), (71, 1), (73, 4), (78, 2), (81, 1), (83, 1), (89, 1), (96, 4), (101, 109)]
```